# Resize an image (pixel art image) JAVA ANDROID

Tags: android, image, resize, scale, pixel

Im developing an app about Pokemon (the japanese videogame...).
Here is my problem: I want to show some images of pokemons. Those images (from the videogames) are made pixel by pixel. I want to show them on the phones exactly how they are. So at first I set the layout_width and layout_height of my imageview in px, with the same value of the image I have downloaded. In the eclipse AVD it looks good, but in a phone the image is too small (physical size). Then I tried to set the layout_width and layout_height of the imageview in mm, so the physical size in the computer and in the phone would be the same. In this mode, the image in the phone looses quality. Then I started think and when someone is playing a Pokemon game in them phone the images look good in a reasonable size  and without loosing quality, so what I want should be possible.
Any ideas ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The best method is to **convert image** into your **desired resolution** which will fit your UI perfectly as you want. Don't use **layout_width** or **layout_height** just convert your image into that resolution.. 
[try this link for converting image into desired resolution without losing image quality](http://www.garyshood.com/imageconvert/)